# Replacing whip on AC condenser

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

[image]I'm trying to replace the whip on my ac condenser and disconnect but the previous whip was not color coded and I'm not sure where the red and black should go.

[image]

Comment: Are we talking about the condensing unit end of the whip, or the house wiring end of the whip? Can you post photos?

Comment: Red and black are only colored different because it matters on some circuits.  It does not matter on this one, which is why the last one is black and black.   They are interchangeable, and don't need to be distinguished from each other.  They do need to be distinguished from ground.  You could mark the red one black with electrical tape if you really wanted to, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I am talking about both ends. If it doesn't matter were red/black go, then I will need to know which ends need to connect. If I put the red on the left and black on the right in the disconnect, where do red/black go then on the condenser unit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two colored leads and one green then it does not matter which place the red goes and which place the black goes.  They are interchangeable. The green or 'bare' wire is not interchangeable with either of the colored leads. The Green must be the ground and it goes between the container of the disconnect to the body of the condenser.  No place else. The colored leads well interchangeably go between the two pole fuse block or the two pole breaker in the disconnect and land on the two pole contactor in the condenser.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I've added photos, my only question now is if I wire the red to the left side of the disconnect and the black to the right side, then where would red and black go on the condenser unit? The only markings I can see are the numbers 11 and 23.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the US and that condenser takes 240 volts, then it doesn't matter which is red and black. It will work whichever way you connect it.

Comment: Yes, I am in the US. Once red and black are connected to one side, then it would matter where they go inside the condenser correct? I assume that it's not interchangeable once one side is connected.

Comment: No, they are interchangeable. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Longneck is right.  No matter how you do it, you can't mix them up.  Let me speak to another thing;  first from the name plate on the out door unit find out what the minimum circuit capacity. Then breaker this thing down to no bigger than it needs to be, either in the disconnect or in the house.  Then size your whip wires properly to the load.  If you need wires as large as I see in the picture, get some chair lugs to make a proper place to land the conductors on the contactor.  If all you need is single strand solid conductor, they can be landed properly with this type of contactor.